# Stock notifier for OSX

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, notifications

I am looking for a stock notifier for osx (macbook pro). Is there anything available ? Perhaps, integrated with Growl or Osx notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [iStock](http://istocks-widget.en.softonic.com/mac) widget for your Mac's dashboard?

[image]

An other option is [StockMeter](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/32939/stockmeter/) which has Growl support indeed and you can install it in the menu-bar of your Mac, so you've got fast access to the data.

[image]